# What is the size of ActionBar in pixels?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to know the exact size of ActionBar in pixels so to apply correct background image.

Answer (score 611, accepted):

To retrieve the height of the ActionBar in XML, just use

```
?android:attr/actionBarSize
```

or if you're an ActionBarSherlock or AppCompat user, use this

```
?attr/actionBarSize
```

If you need this value at runtime, use this

```
final TypedArray styledAttributes = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                    new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
mActionBarSize = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
styledAttributes.recycle();
```

If you need to understand where this is defined:

1. The attribute name itself is defined in the platform's [/res/values/attrs.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml)
2. The platform's [themes.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) picks this attribute and assigns a value to it.
3. The value assigned in step 2 depends on different device sizes, which are defined in [various dimens.xml files](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/search?q=action_bar_default_height&type=Code) in the platform, ie. *core/res/res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml*

Comment: Great answer. I know the way to dig this informations, but to search this answer was much faster +1. Your answer is also a great hint how to search such things.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use `@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height` directly (ActionBarComapt) and it worked (on mdpi device). But trying to get this value on Samsung Galaxy SIII returned me wrong value. That is because `values-xlarge` (somehow) is more preferred than `values-land` when in landscape mode. Referring to the attribute instead works like a charm.

Comment: @AZ13 I would like to add that `android.R.attr.actionBarSize` will resolve to 0 size on pre-3.0 devices. So when using `ActionBarCompat` one would stick to `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize` instead.

Comment: The guy asked it in pixels. I suppose actionBarSize returns the dp value. I got the value 48dp. That means converting it to pixels gives me 96 pixels for xhdpi.

Comment: "android.R.attr.actionBarSize" is not working in android version 2.3, but "R.attr.actionBarSize" is working android all version. just use "R.attr.actionBarSize" instead of "android.R.attr.actionBarSize" and etc.

Comment: This code example returns 74 on Android 5.1 / Nexus 7. The actual actionbar size in GMail app is 85px (measured by taking a screenshot).

Comment: `?attr/actionBarSize` (appcompat) only displayed on android device, but not in android studio...

Comment: ?android:attr/actionBarSize is what works when you migrate to the AndroidX version of the AppCompat library.

Comment: is it in pixels ?

Answer (score 64):

From the de-compiled sources of Android 3.2's `framework-res.apk`, `res/values/styles.xml` contains:

```
<style name="Theme.Holo">
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="actionBarSize">56.0dip</item>
    <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

3.0 and 3.1 seem to be the same (at least from AOSP)...

Comment: What about the different height of the action bar in landscape?

Comment: on 4.0+: default is 48dp, landscape is 40dp, sw600dp is 56dp

Comment: Which is why you should use the android:attr value and not a hardcoded value!

Answer (score 48):

To get the actual height of the Actionbar, you have to resolve the attribute `actionBarSize` at runtime.

```
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
int actionBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(tv.resourceId);
```

Answer (score 35):

One of the Honeycomb samples refers to `?android:attr/actionBarSize`

Comment: Yes, explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#GeneralStyles

Comment: This is the answer if your min sdk is >=11, if you're min is <11, then most likely you're using ABS, then this is the solution: @dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height

Comment: ABS has `?attr/actionBarSize` (note the lack of android namespace) which works on all API levels.

Answer (score 21):

I needed to do replicate these heights properly in a pre-ICS compatibility app and dug into the [framework core source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res). Both answers above are sort of correct.

It basically boils down to using qualifiers. The height is defined by the dimension "action_bar_default_height"

It is defined to 48dip for default. But for -land it is 40dip and for sw600dp it is 56dip.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using the compatibility ActionBar from the recent v7 appcompat support package, you can get the height using

```
@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.dimen.html)

Answer (score 16):

With the new [v7 support library](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/package-summary.html) (21.0.0) the name in `R.dimen` has changed to [@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_**material**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.dimen.html#abc_action_bar_default_height_material).

When upgrading from a previous version of the support lib you should therefore use that value as the actionbar's height

Comment: Perfect! This sure beats `?attr/actionBarSize` if one is looking to match a regular `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using ActionBarSherlock, you can get the height with

```
@dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height
```

Comment: Don't use `abs__`-prefixed resources directly.

Comment: @JakeWharton please tell us how to do it correctly instead, then.

Comment: Create your own dimension so you are not dependent on abs_.

Answer (score 5):

@AZ13's answer is good, but as per the [Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html), the ActionBar should be [at least 48dp high](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html#examples).

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer in Kotlin :

```
val Context.actionBarSize
    get() = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.actionBarSize))
        .let { attrs -> attrs.getDimension(0, 0F).toInt().also { attrs.recycle() } }
```

Usage :

```
val size = actionBarSize                    // Inside Activity
val size = requireContext().actionBarSize   // Inside Fragment
val size = anyView.context.actionBarSize    // Inside RecyclerView ViewHolder
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getActionBarHeight() {
    int actionBarHeight = 0;
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv,
                true))
            actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
                    tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    } else {
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return actionBarHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Class Summary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) is usually a good place to start. I think the getHeight() method should suffice.

EDIT:

If you need the width, it should be the width of the screen (right?) and that can be gathered [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions).

Comment: Strange - getHeight() results in zero.

Comment: in my development, I noticed that it returns zero in onResume(). Hovever calling getActionBar().getHeight() when you actually need it returns a positive >0 value.

Comment: @tos the spec for the getHeight() says that it returns the current width for the ActionBar, which is probably 0 when the view is created

Answer (score 0):

On my Galaxy S4 having > 441dpi > 1080 x 1920 > 
Getting Actionbar height with getResources().getDimensionPixelSize I got 144 pixels.

Using formula px = dp x (dpi/160), I was using 441dpi, whereas my device lies 
 
in the category 480dpi. so putting that confirms the result.

Answer (score 0):

I did in this way for myself, this helper method should come in handy for someone:

```
private static final int[] RES_IDS_ACTION_BAR_SIZE = {R.attr.actionBarSize};

/**
 * Calculates the Action Bar height in pixels.
 */
public static int calculateActionBarSize(Context context) {
    if (context == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    Resources.Theme curTheme = context.getTheme();
    if (curTheme == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    TypedArray att = curTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(RES_IDS_ACTION_BAR_SIZE);
    if (att == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    float size = att.getDimension(0, 0);
    att.recycle();
    return (int) size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Source: appcompact-1.6.1/res/values

```
<item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material</item>


// values.xml
<dimen name="abc_action_bar_default_height_material">56dp</dimen>

//values-land.xml
<dimen name="abc_action_bar_default_height_material">48dp</dimen>

//values-sw600dp-v13.xml
<dimen name="abc_action_bar_default_height_material">64dp</dimen>
```