# Android tablet development screen resolution and size

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet

I am developing for Android tablet with 10.1 screen size with 800 x 1280 resolution. I read that the control bar (with buttons: back, home etc.) is 80px height (not sure). So i told the app UI designer to send me the design in 720 x 1280 resolution, but then i have noticed that there is also bar on top of the screen (with the app icon and name), i know how to make it disappear but i would like to keep it. I don't know the height of that bar and what resolution to ask from the UI designer. Can you please tell me what resolution i need?

Comment: why don't you just play with the height until you find it? also repeat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165830/what-is-the-size-of-actionbar-in-pixels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

Screen height: 800px

Status Bar (Bottom): 48px

Action Bar (Top): 56px

Middle:696px

Answer (score 0):

You should not bind your UI to specific and fixed sizes on Android, if possible try re-thinking the graphic elements in terms of stretchable nine patches and android xml resources such as gradients and shapes, in case you don't know them here's some link:

Nine-Patches: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Drawable resources: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

And here's a link to a similar question with some values for the height of the status bar in Android: [Height of status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407256/height-of-status-bar-in-android)