# Get the Height of ActionBar

Tags: android

I am using Actionbar in my application.
I want the Height of the ActionBar programatically hence I am using :

```
ActionBar.getHeight();
```

But I am getting 0 value of Height.
So How can I get the Height of ActionBar?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the alternative of `ActionBar.getHeight()` 
 If anyone facing the same issue then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13216807/1186689) link is useful.

> While @birdy's answer is an option if you want to explicitly control
>   the ActionBar size there is a way to pull it up without locking the
>   size that I found in support documentation. It's a little awkward but
>   it's worked for me. You'll need a context, this example would be valid
>   in an Activity. ~ [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650322/anthony)

```
// Calculate ActionBar's height 
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue(); 
if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
    actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
}
```

Comment: "android.R.attr.actionBarSize" is not working in android version 2.3, but "R.attr.actionBarSize" is working android all version. just use "R.attr.actionBarSize" instead of "android.R.attr.actionBarSize" and etc.

Comment: Anyone know how to it in java (javafx)?

Answer (score 5):

Below code will help too. You may need to change getContext() to this

```
final TypedArray styledAttributes = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                    new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
mActionBarSize = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
styledAttributes.recycle();
```

The answer is copied from this question [What is the size of ActionBar in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165830/what-is-the-size-of-actionbar-in-pixels)

For the newer version of Android you could simply do this:

```
getActionBar().getHeight()
```

Comment: appreciate it @Tim Hong. I will look into that.

Comment: For the newer version of Android you could simply do this:

    getActionBar().getHeight()

Comment: getHeight() can return 0 even if isShowing is true (probably during its animation). You may need to use the attributes method in some cases.

Comment: I see. Interesting! Thanks for that dpk.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to find actionbar height is from Activity onPrepareOptionMenu method.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           ....
           int actionBarHeight = getActionBar().getHeight());
           .....
    }
```