# ActionBarSherlock size?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, photoshop, pixel

What is ActionBarSherlock size in **pixels** please ? Specifically the height, I need to design a background and I need this dimension in pixels.

And I have already searched and all I found was sizes in dp.

Comment: Why can't you get it in runtime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the size of ActionBar in pixels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165830/what-is-the-size-of-actionbar-in-pixels). A simple [Google search would have thrown this result](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr#safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+action+bar+height+in+pixels&oq=android+action+bar+size+pixels&gs_l=hp.3.0.0i22i30.92571.94076.1.95570.7.7.0.0.0.0.173.1001.0j7.7.0....0.0..1c.1.20.psy-ab.AJ66CGOcUMI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49967636%2Cd.bmk%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.jOYpRJj4zMA.O&fp=926a8da4084916e4&biw=1440&bih=775)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I have already checked, I need the size in *pixels* so that I can draw a background in photoshop (photoshop doesn't support dp as far as I know)

Comment: you can convert dp in pixels . You have simply to multiply the height for the screen density

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert dp into pixels and use in your project .
I hope it will solve your poblem.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously,

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
int height = actionBar.getHeight();
```