# how to add actionbarsherlock menu to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I am using both actionbarsherlock and slidingmenu objects

the point is, I want my menu - which is sliding to do the following

1. push the currently visible screen aside, along with its actionbar
2. the fragment that is displayed inside the menu to have a different actionbar

how do i do that?

I've set everything to make 1 work 
but the fragment is missing the menu - how to add it ?

Comment: Fragmants dont' have an ActionBar. ActionBars just belong to the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple ActionBar in the same activity.
Best thing you could probably do, is not make the ActionBar slide with the menu, while starting/finishing an [ActionMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html) when you open up/close the sliding menu.
Or if you really want to slide the ActionBar, then simply create a view in the menu fragment that will looks like an action bar.

Comment: how do i programmatically adjust that view to the actionbar's height?

Comment: Someone already answer that question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13026919/795245), let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use a custom layout in your actionbar and manipulate it by adding an animation so that it looks like the actionbar slides out and it is pushed by another actionbar when the menu slides in. The object would be the same, but the user perception will be of a sliding action bar pushing away the previous one.