# Animating ActionBar's icon

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-drawable

I have an `ActionBar` icon (the main one on the left, not an action item) that I would like to animate.

I am setting my `ActionBar`'s icon in my `Activity` like this:

`getSupportActionBar().setIcon(icon)`

where `icon` is a `Drawable` produced by a library that converts a custom XML view into a bitmap. This XML view is a `RelativeLayout` with a background image and a `TextView` on top.

Today, when I have to update the `TextView` I simply re-generate the `icon` and call `setIcon` again. Instead, I would like to get a hold of my `TextView` and apply some animation effect on it, like fade-out and then fade-in after updating it (maybe never having to call `setIcon`, just re-use the same one).

Not sure how to go about this. Can someone recommend an approach?

**EDIT**: trying this approach:

In `MyActivity`:

```
Drawable myDrawable = new MyDrawable();
supportActionBar.setIcon(myDrawable);
```

and:

```
public class MyDrawable extends Drawable {
    private Paint paint;
    private RectF rect;

    public MyDrawable() {
        this.paint = new Paint();
        this.rect = new RectF();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setARGB(255, 0, 255, 0);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        rect.right = 20f;
        rect.bottom = 20f;

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 0.5f, 0.5f, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        paint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
    }
}
```

Nothing shows up. I verified that `onDraw` gets called. Something suspicious to me is that `canvas` has both height & width set to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper approach for it would be to forget the XML layout and create a custom `Drawable`.

An instance of this custom drawable will be set to the icon on the ActionBar and call `invalidateSelf()` whenever necessary to redraw (due to animation, for example).

The drawable can hold reference to other drawables (e.g. BitmapDrawable to have something from the `/res/` folder or a Color or Gradient drawable for a background shade) and call (for example) `bgDraw.draw(canvas)` during the `onDraw` callback.

It can also draw stuff directly on the canvas that is given to it during `onDraw` callback. With the canvas you can draw circle, lines, areas, path and text directly on it.

**edit:**

very simple animation example (didn't check the code, likely typos):

```
private long animationTime;
public void doAnimation(){
    animationTime = System.currentTimeMilis() + 3000; // 3 seconds
    invalidateSelf();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    // do your drawing.
    // You can use difference between
    // currentTimeMilis and animationTime for status/position
   ...

    // at the end
    if(animationTime > System.currentTimeMilis())
         invalidateSelf();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying this approach but can't get anything to draw so far. My custom drawable's `onDraw` method receives a canvas of height and width '1', on which I call drawRoundRect for a (0,0)-(20,20) RectF. Any pointer?

Comment: override `getIntrinsicWidth` and `getIntrinsicHeight` and return some values. Also override `setBounds` and initialise any sizing you need there.

Comment: Thanks, I have a basic bitmap + text working now. I am providing arbitrary intrinsic & bound values, would like to know more. Also for animating, I wonder if I should call invalidateSelf from onDraw and maintain a state machine. Any pointers would be helpful if you have.

Comment: You can call `invalidateSelf()` from anywhere that suits you, including `onDraw` to keep the animation flowing. How you organize is very much up to you, but I just put a very simple way on the answer (check the edit). You can also use the `onLevelChange` callback that is built-in on Drawble to trigger different stuff (example, you set the `drawable.setLevel(1000)` to animate 1 second)

Comment: regarding the arbitrary intrinsic sizes: you comment you're using it for the actionbar icon, so I reckon the size you should return are the actionbar icon size. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165830/what-is-the-size-of-actionbar-in-pixels