# L-release-like Touch Ripple animation on pre-L

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I love the new Touch Ripple animation that was introduced in the new Android L-release as part of the new UI philosophy Material Design.

You can find a video of it in the official design spec under surface reaction here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html

It's basically a dark-gray circle that fades in at the center of the view and grows as it fades out again, eventually filling the whole view with a light gray before disappearing again.

I'd like to add the very same animation to a view in my app that is targetting ICS.

I am a bit clueless on how to add this animation in my application. The official docs at http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html don't seem to cover animations that happen "inside a view".
Also, I'd like not to use pre-drawn frame animations (one png resource per frame) if possible.

How would I go about implementing that?
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I would wait until tomorrow (when the new L-related APIs will be released) so we can see if there will be something in the support library to support this.

Comment: the best way is using a custom drawable. Please see my previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213356/animating-actionbars-icon/24214040#24214040 (make sure to also read the comments on the answer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something I cooked up quickly, far from ideal, but hey, it's something: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/nhaarman/dfe0631a820bccb7a3b3)

Basically drawing a circle based on an animated radius. To get the exact L-effect, some more tweaking should be done. The interesting code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull final MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        mDownX = event.getX();
        mDownY = event.getY();

        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "radius", 0, getWidth() * 3.0f);
        animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        animator.setDuration(400);
        animator.start();
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void setRadius(final float radius) {
    mRadius = radius;
    if (mRadius > 0) {
        RadialGradient radialGradient = new RadialGradient(
                mDownX,
                mDownY,
                mRadius * 3,
                Color.TRANSPARENT,
                Color.BLACK,
                Shader.TileMode.MIRROR
        );
        mPaint.setShader(radialGradient);
    }
    invalidate();
}

private Path mPath = new Path();
private Path mPath2 = new Path();

@Override
protected void onDraw(@NonNull final Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    mPath2.reset();
    mPath2.addCircle(mDownX, mDownY, mRadius, Path.Direction.CW);

    canvas.clipPath(mPath2);

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.addCircle(mDownX, mDownY, mRadius / 3, Path.Direction.CW);

    canvas.clipPath(mPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);

    canvas.drawCircle(mDownX, mDownY, mRadius, mPaint);
}
```

---

In their talk "What's new in Android", they talked about that this animation actually happens on a separate "Render thread", which will make its debut in the L-release. This will allow smoother animations, even when the UI thread is busy inflating, or doing anything else expensive.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll eventually use a combination of your answer and Budius' comment.

Comment: Your idea is great ,but the gradient should remain while the user is touching the button, no?

Comment: Is there a noticeable performance impact on pre-L devices without the Render Thread?

Answer (score 5):

My answer is kind of late but I wanted to share my solution too. I created another class called TouchEffectAnimator with the idea of Niek Haarman. Thanks to Mr. Haarman by the way.

You can see the class and an example usage of it [on this gist](https://gist.github.com/eluleci/6e0d02c766b27f6a5253). Also I'll explain it simply.

The class contains all the necessary methods and variables in it and creates the same animation that Android L (preview) currently has. For using this class:

- Create a custom view. (in gist example I created a LinearLayout)
- Initialise the TouchEffectAnimator object.
- Define some attributes of it like color, effect type, duration and clip corners size.
- Call the **onTouchEvent** method of TouchEffectAnimator inside the **view's onTouchEvent**.
- Call the **onDraw** method of TouchEffectAnimator inside the **view's onDraw**.

and that's it. But there are two things that should be done for this class to work properly.

- There should be some **OnClickListener** on the view to get the UP touch event.
- There should be a custom or transparent background set to the view. If nothing is set as background the animation is not shown.

I hope it works for you too.

P.S. I created this class for my library project [Android FlatUI Kit](https://github.com/eluleci/FlatUI). You can see the usage of this class in FlatButton class as well.

Comment: Nice, thank you for sharing this, I'm going to try and tune your TouchEffectAnimator, it works perfectly !

Comment: This is working awesome except for a small inconsistency that I have observed. If the FIRST touch on button is a QUICK one(state_pressed will be only very little time), animation is not proper.