# Material design toolbar on devices pre-lollipop

Tags: android, tablet, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm flollowing next tutorial:

- https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

I want do that similar design:

[image: md]

I know i need use Two toolbars.

**values/themes.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.MiThema" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
    <!--<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>-->


    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
    </resources>
```

**class.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

public class RegistrarInciTraActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registrar_inci_traf_layout);

        //ocultamos ActionBar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();


       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

**layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- The toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- drawer view -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start">

            <!-- drawer content -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- normal content view -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- The rest of content view -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Tha code report one error on "setSupportActionBar(toolbar);":

[image: md2]

**(first problem) ¿What is the problem about that?** ***(SOLVED)***

**(Second problem)**

On my layout appear

> **"?attr/actionBarSize"** and **"?attr/colorPrimary"**

**Where do I have to declare those attributes?**

**(Third problem)**

When I do two toolbars only appear once of them and I want one inside the other to display content.

[image: md3]

**What I do have to display both toolbars?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I can give you an answer for your first problem. It is very simple - you only have to read the message given by your IDE. You're using the wrong toolbar. The toolbar you're trying to pass to the setSupportActionBar-Method is from the package android.widget. But you've to use the toolbar from the package android.support.v7.widget. So your imports are wrong - correct them and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

As 1st Problem is solved, let me try **Second** one,

First of all, you do not have to define these values anywhere, they are pre-defined.

1. ***"?attr/actionBarSize"*** : this is a default value provided by Android. You will get it at `android.support.v7.appcompat/R`,but it will give you an int reference. If you want to know the actual height of the Actionbar, you have to resolve the attribute `actionBarSize` at runtime. Follow this Link : [Get ActionBar Size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167086/3480938)(answer given on other SO Q.).
   Also Now with **Material Design**, Google shared some standards to be used while designing new Apps (or upgrading old one) in Material Design. You can follow those norms here : [LayoutMetrics & keylines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#)
2. ***"?attr/colorPrimary"*** : This is also a pre-defined value. You can get it at `android.support.v7.appcompat/R`, but it will give you an int reference. But if you want a custom background color to your `ToolBar` then just add an appropriate color palette, `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"` and define `colorPrimary` value in `color.xml`. Use this site to get different color values : [Material Palette](http://www.materialpalette.com/) (I prefer this site).