# How to calulate android:paddingTop manully?

Tags: android-layout

I set the overlay as follows:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

I have `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`, how do do I double it?

`android:paddingTop="2*?attr/actionBarSize"` wouldn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165830/what-is-the-size-of-actionbar-in-pixels (What is the size of the ActionBar in pixels)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do double android:paddingTop="2*?attr/actionBarSize"