# No resource found that matches given name... after upgrade of compileSdkVerion and buildToolsVersion

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I had these two lines in my build.gradle file:

```
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
```

I changed them to:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
```

And I also changed support library to match the build tools version:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
```

Now, when building my project I get this error:

```
Error:(21, 33) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'paddingTop' with value '@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height').
```

That relates to a line in a layout file:

```
android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: is this in one of your layout files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26489158/599346

Comment: That value is part of the [v7 library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.dimen.html) (and `_material` is on the end of it, now)

Comment: @tyczj this is the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `?attr/actionBarSize`for the actionbar size.

Like this `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`

The Support Library now hides xml resources. You need to use that if you want to get that dimension.

Answer (score 3):

You should change from @dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height to ?attr/actionBarSize

As you changed your support library version, your dimens changed too. The values come from the resources in the support library, using ?attr/actionBarSize is the compatible way to avoid having this breaks.

You can better understand how the dimens and themes works in this answer. [What is the size of ActionBar in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165830/what-is-the-size-of-actionbar-in-pixels)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the issue was with other libraries that depend on app versions less than com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0 , so what i suggest is go to the github/maven repo of the libraries that you have and see if they have updated their libraries to a newer version.if so then update your dependency list

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the additional library of this project to have a try.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: What is your minimum sdk version?You can set it to 19 or 20 and see if still have a error.