# Filling the whole screen with Gridview items

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have a GridView (with 2 columns and 2 rows) and want to stretch the rows to fill the whole screen. It should look the same on all devices.

[image]

That means I don't want some empty space under the last row. So I searched a little bit and found a solution to set the minimum height of the GridView dynamically with following code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

In addition I added these lines of code in my Adapter:

```
gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.act_main_menu_sub, null);
gridView.setMinimumHeight(ActMainMenu.height/2);
```

But now it looks like this:

[image]

The View is scrollable now and the items have the same size. But it doesn't fit on the screen.

Here is the code of my layout including the GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/layout_main_menu"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#b2b2b2"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:padding="2dp"
    app:titleMarginStart="20dp"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base.TitleTextStyle"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="MASTERFITNESS TRAINERSCHULUNG"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<!--android:columnWidth="160dp"-->
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp"></GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Maybe inside gridView.setMinimumHeight(ActMainMenu.height/2) you have to take in account the padding, did you try?

Comment: What should I do with the padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your 2nd screen shots in the height calculation.  `metrics.heightPixels` gives you the full height of the screen, including the toolbar and any margins you have.  These should 1st be subtracted out, then divide the screen in half.

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    // your layout has 10dp margin (top & bottom) + 20 dp between grid items, 10+10+20=40
    int marginSizeDp = 40;
    float scale = metrics.density;
    int marginSizePx = Math.round (marginSizeDp * scale);

    int appBarHeight = getAppBarHeight();

    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int minHt = Math.round((height - marginSizePx - appBarHeight)/2);
    gridView.setMinimumHeight(minHt);
```

Get the toolbar height thanks to AZ13 at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167086/7292819

```
    // returns height of app bar in pixels
    private int getAppBarHeight() {
        final TypedArray styledAttributes = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
        int appBarHeight = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
        styledAttributes.recycle();

        return appBarHeight;
    }
```

Truthfully, if this layout is static (there's only 4 items, no scrolling, little or no changing of the content of each item), I probably wouldn't bother with a GridView & adapter.  A RelativeLayout or GridLayout might be better.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to use LinearLayout with weights. This works very well. Thank you for your tip.

Comment: I was thinking about that last night after I finished this answer.  Was going to add weighted LinearLayout this morning.  You will get warnings about nested weights but I don't think performance will be affected much on a simple layout like this.